# MySQL: Add a WHERE in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have the following table:

[image]

SequenceNumber are always a multiple of 10. I would like to get, for a specific `cpId`, the smallest free sequence number (still in a multiple of 10). For example, for `cpId = 1`, the smallest available should be `20`. For `cpId = 2`, it should be `10`.

I have the following statement to get the smallest available sequenceNumber for all cpId, and I don't know how I can add a `WHERE cpId = x` inside the statement:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.sequenceNumber + 10) AS nextID
FROM LogicalConnection t1
   LEFT JOIN LogicalConnection t2
       ON t1.sequenceNumber + 10 = t2.sequenceNumber
WHERE t2.sequenceNumber IS NULL;
```

DB fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ag67AkFzfwPZEva8bTN7Q3/2#&togetherjs=L9nHb3Uu7O

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you aware that your approach will fail miserably if you have concurrent transactions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, this is protected by semaphore.

Comment: If you want the records with smallest sequenceNumber, why is  for `cpId = `1, the smallest is `20` and for `cpId = 2` the smallest is `10`? please help me to understand.

Comment: @sveer First sequence number is 10, then it is always incremented by 10 (10,20,30,40...). For cpId =1, 10 and 30 are used, but not 20, so that's the smallest available one (I don't use 0). For cpId = 2, 10 is not used and that's the smallest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()` to get the next number and then some simple logic:

```
select cpid,
       (case when min_sn > 10 then 10
             else min(sequenceNumber) + 10
        end)
from (select t.*,
             min(sequenceNumber) over (partition by cpid) as min_sn,
             lead(sequenceNumber) over (partition by cpid order by sequenceNumber) as next_sn
      from t
     ) t
where next_sn is null or next_sn <> sequenceNumber + 10
group by cpid, min_sn;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to join both tables on cpId column and group the rows with similar cpId.
Where can be used to filter rows.
Below query gives you the cpId and their corresponding next available minimum sequence number.

```
SELECT t1.cpId, MIN(t1.sequenceNumber + 10) AS nextID
FROM LogicalConnection t1
LEFT JOIN LogicalConnection t2
       ON t1.sequenceNumber + 10 = t2.sequenceNumber
       and t1.cpId = t2.cpId
group by (t1.cpId)
```

Comment: This return 30 instead of 10 for cpId = 2. Will try to modify your statement :)